# TableView custom swipe action - Rxswift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Here is how i use RxSwift in my code:

My news variable in ViewModel:

```
var news = PublishSubject<[Article]>()
```

Extensions for using Rxswift with tableview.

```
extension HomeViewController {
func designTableView() {
    newsTable.separatorStyle = .none
    newsTable.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
}

func createCellView() {
    homeViewModel.news.bind(to: newsTable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell", cellType: NewsCell.self)) { _, news, cell in

        cell.newsTitle.text = news.title
        cell.newsImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: news.urlToImage ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "photo"))

    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func whenNewsSelected() {
    newsTable.rx.modelSelected(Article.self).bind { article in
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsDetail") as? NewsDetails
        vc?.article = article
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}

func setDelegateForTableView() {
    newsTable.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

}

What I want to do is, adding a Favorite action to cell. I tried the code belove but I don't how can I access the news data on that row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{
    let FlagAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Fav", handler: { (_: UIContextualAction, _: UIView, success: (Bool) -> Void) in
        print("osman")
        success(true)
    })
    FlagAction.backgroundColor = .orange

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [FlagAction])
}
```

Can someone help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var news = PublishSubject<[Article]>()` use `let news = BehaviorSubject<[Article]>(value: [])` (Note: Subjects should *always* be let constants, never var.)

Then when you need access to the articles, you can do:

```
let articles = (try? homeViewModel.news.value()) ?? []
```

I don't normally recommend using Subjects but the alternative here is to write your own DataSource type or use RxDataSources and that may be too deep down the rabbit hole for you.

**if you do want to go down the rabbit hole**

Bring in RxDataSources or write your own data source and make it a member of your view controller:

```
let dataSource = MyDataSource<Article, NewsCell>(cellIdentifier: "cell") { _, news, cell in
    cell.newsTitle.text = news.title
    cell.newsImage?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: news.urlToImage ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(systemName: "photo"))
}
```

use it like this:

```
func createCellView() {
    homeViewModel.news
        .bind(to: newsTable.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Then you can access the articles like this:

```
let articles = dataSource.elements
```

Here's what a basic data source looks like. This does everything the default RxCocoa data source does.

```
class MyDataSource<Element, Cell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, RxTableViewDataSourceType
where Cell: UITableViewCell {
    private(set) var elements: [Element] = []
    private let cellIdentifier: String
    private let configureCell: (Int, Element, Cell) -> Void

    init(cellIdentifier: String, configureCell: @escaping (Int, Element, Cell) -> Void) {
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        self.configureCell = configureCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: RxSwift.Event<[Element]>) {
        guard case let .next(elements) = observedEvent else { return }
        self.elements = elements
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        elements.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? Cell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        let element = elements[indexPath.row]
        configureCell(indexPath.row, element, cell)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your big help. I will read your second solution try to understand it. Thank you so much.